# Writing a shell script to get dependency list in makefiles

Tags: parsing, makefile, dependencies

I have a requirement to build a dependency list of all servers to objects to the actual source code.

It stems out of the need for the team that builds code to be able to know what servers to build knowing the source files that got modified.

Is there a way I can use some tool(besides make depend), or write scripts that can parse makefiles and return with a list of all dependencies that I can store in a database.

Comment: What is your input in this situation? Existing make files? Deployed servers? External information (someone just knows the information at the moment)? Are you just trying to get the list of dependencies of a given makefile target (built file)?

Comment: I'm using existing makefiles and there are a lot of them :). I need to build a mapping in a database that can show if any source code file got modified, which targets(servers) should be rebuilt.

Comment: Do you mean targets (as in makefile targets)? Do you mean servers (as in actual boxes? Are you trying to tie built code to machines that have it deployed on them?

Comment: Yes targets is makefile targets. Servers are target executables. The makefiles I have are structured something like this.

Comment: I'm confused. If what you want is to rebuild the correct executables when their dependencies change that's exactly what make does and you are using make already you said. Is something not working correctly? Is there some reason you want this in an external db? Am I missing some other detail here?

Comment: Ha sorry about the confusion Etan. I should have articulated it better. Here goes another attempt. This is for a pretty large application code base, which has a dedicated team that gets build requests. In the build requests, developers ask for specific servers(read executables) to be built so that there code changes are compiled and deployed. These build requests sometimes miss out on mentioning certain executables that should have been rebuilt. The idea is to build a dependency mapping in some form of database so that the developers just send in the list of files they changed.

Comment: The team can just look at the executables that should be rebuilt from this dependency mapping and avoid any chance of stuff being missed out.

Comment: Right. That's what make *does*. That's its *whole job*. To rebuild all the things that depend on resources that have changed. You should need nothing more than to run `make` in a correctly maintained project tree and make should automatically rebuild all the objects (executables, libraries, images, etc.) that depend on any resource that has changed more recently than the output object itself.

Comment: The problem is that there is only once during the week that we have a full build of the code, which would(as you said) take care of everything. Besides that there are partial build requests to only build a subset of the executables, which is where the problem arises. If developers miss mentioning 1 of the executables that should be rebuilt, the changes do not go through. We're trying to get a tap on those so we can ensure everything that should have been compiled, does get exactly that.

Comment: So are these dynamic sets of executables that may be requested in arbitrary combinations? Or are the sets of executables constant?

Comment: You might be able to play games with the `-o` and `-W` arguments to make to explicitly tell it to ignore all files and then explicitly pay attention to the list of files you were given... that might get you what you want but I don't know (and this is rather a gross hack).

Comment: Arbitrary combinations. I cant touch the makefiles and I can confirm that they are badly written. In this case, when they run a full build they do a fresh checkout of the code and build everything again. Somehow just taking an update and running make does not have the desired result. So, there are incremental build requests through the week asking only certain binaries to be rebuilt.

Comment: Badly written make files make me sad. =( Anyway. I don't think there is any good way to get what you want out of make except in the very simplest of cases (and even then it wouldn't be pretty). That being said you may want to look into one of the make accelerators since they claim to watch the build and grab the dependency trees out of that process for use later.